# How do armors from equipment patches work?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I've been getting tons of different equipment patches lately in the game, but I'm not sure how the ones giving armor does affect my defense in the battles. Does X armor means X or a certain percentage less HP damage you get in each turn? Does it give you extra shield? Or something completely different?

And after all should I get the patches giving armor or extra HP, which one is more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Armor in *Stick of Truth* functions as flat damage reduction, per hit.

Thus, if you have 100 Armor, and are hit by an attack that does 1000 damage, you'll only take 900 damage.

The thing that's great about Armor however, is that this applies *to every hit*, and tons of enemies have basic attacks that hit 2, 3, or even 4 times. So, if our hypothetical enemy, instead of hitting once for 1000, instead hits twice for 500, you'll only take **800** damage. What this means is that as you get hit more often, Armor becomes better and better, relative to just stacking HP; of course, the shorter any given fight is, or the less frequently your new kid gets hit, the more useful HP is instead of Armor. Armor also has the additional bonus that in conjunction with certain weapons, it also *adds to your attack*, as there are a number of weapons that add, 2, 3, or even 4 times your Armor to your damage.

All that said, I'd generally advise, that, unless you're using one of those weapons with an Armor multiplier effect (which is not a bad strategy! If you stack armor from items and patches, these can be the strongest weapons in the game, and you'll mitigate a ton of damage. It's especially good if you're bad at QTE blocking.), that you **not** use Armor *or* HP patches. In general, mitigating incoming damage with blocks is plenty, and patches are best used on either offensive boosts, or on bonuses to *regeneration* of HP, or PP. You'll generally get much better results.

Comment: Does that mean even if the opponent doesn't hit multiple times you'll get 100 less damage every time someone hits you? Then, it is more sensible to have 100 armor instead of just 100 hp, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, you always take at least 1 damage from every attack. What is also not mentioned is that armour does not mitigate the damage from effects. Say you have 100 armour but you are bleeding. If you take 300 damage from the bleeding effect, you will take it in full without the armour reducing the damage. Hence, armour is also less effective against enemies who afflict status conditions as their main damage source. Those include Bleeding and Grossed Out but can include insta-death attacks as well such as Screwed.

Answer (score 0):

The ones that give armor pad your defense, think of it like defense in pokemon, the higher the defense the less damage you will take from an attack. It will not give you a shield, I beat the game and collected almost all patches and have yet to see one that gives you a shield. What patch you use is entirely up to you, if you want more hp rather than more defense then go with the hp. It is all about your playing style. Though you should use what ever one will give you the highest boost, making your character as strong as it can be.